# Testing out some LWJGL OpenGL, won't make box. What should I do?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, geometry, lwjgl

Had this working on OpenGL ES 1.0 & 2.0.

Goal: Make a box, then display it

Won't work with LWJGL on Win 7. Loads a green box (as it should), and then starts to display a bunch of really thick white lines that won't stay as a box. There is a lot of flickering. Here is a picture.

[image]

Here is the code for windows.

Main.java

```
package play.box;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Main {

    public static final boolean VSYNC = true;

    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;

    public static final boolean FULLSCREEN = false;

    protected boolean running = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            start();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void start() throws LWJGLException {
        Display.setTitle("Display example");
        Display.setResizable(false);
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(VSYNC);
        Display.setFullscreen(FULLSCREEN);

        Display.create();

        // Setup OpenGL
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glOrtho(-3, 3, -2, 2, -1, 1);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

        new Renderer().run();
    }

}
```

Renderer.java

```
package play.box;

import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Renderer implements Runnable {

    public Renderer() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested() && !Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            // Rendering //
            /*GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES);

            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex2f(0.0f, 1.0f);

            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex2f(1.0f, 1.0f);

            GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
            GL11.glVertex2f(1.0f, -1.0f);

            GL11.glEnd();*/

            Box box = new Box();
            box.draw();
            // End of Rendering //

            Display.update();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Box.java

```
package play.box;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;

public class Box {

    private float verticies[] = {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, // Left Top (0)
            -1.0f, -1.0f, // Left Bottom (1)
             1.0f, -1.0f, // Right Bottom (2)
             1.0f,  1.0f  // Right Top (4)
    };
    private short indicies[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
    };

    private FloatBuffer vertBuff;
    private ShortBuffer indexBuff;

    public Box() {
        this.setupBuffers();
    }

    private void setupBuffers() {
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.verticies.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        this.vertBuff.put(this.verticies);
        this.vertBuff.position(0);

        ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.indicies.length * 2);
        pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.indexBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
        this.indexBuff.put(this.indicies);
        this.indexBuff.position(0);
    }

    public void draw() {
        GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        GL11.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, this.vertBuff);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, this.indexBuff);

        GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    }

}
```

**Updated Code:**

```
package play.box;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30;

public class Box {

    private float verticies[] = {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, // Left Top (0)
            -1.0f, -1.0f, // Left Bottom (1)
             1.0f, -1.0f, // Right Bottom (2)
             1.0f,  1.0f  // Right Top (4)
    };
    private short indicies[] = {
            0, 1, 2,
            2, 3, 0
    };

    private FloatBuffer vertBuff;
    private ShortBuffer indexBuff;

    private int vbo_handle;
    private int ibo_handle;
    private int vao_handle;

    private String vShaderStr =
              "attribute vec4 vPosition; \n"
            + "void main() {             \n"
            + "  gl_Position = vPosition;\n"
            + "}                         \n";

    private String fShaderStr =
              "precision mediump float;                   \n"
            + "void main() {                              \n"
            + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); \n"
            + "}                                          \n";

    private int vertexShader;
    private int fragmentShader;
    private int programObject;

    public Box() {
    }

    public void create() {
        ByteBuffer bBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.verticies.length * 4);
        bBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.vertBuff = bBuff.asFloatBuffer();
        this.vertBuff.put(this.verticies);
        //this.vertBuff.flip();
        this.vertBuff.position(0);

        ByteBuffer pbBuff = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(this.indicies.length * 2);
        pbBuff.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        this.indexBuff = pbBuff.asShortBuffer();
        this.indexBuff.put(this.indicies);
        //this.indexBuff.flip();
        this.indexBuff.position(0);

        // Create VBO
        this.vbo_handle = GL15.glGenBuffers();

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo_handle);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertBuff, GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Create IBO
        this.ibo_handle = GL15.glGenBuffers();

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.ibo_handle);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.indexBuff, GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

        // Create VAO
        this.vao_handle = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao_handle);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_handle);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo_handle);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        // Setup Shaders
        this.vertexShader = this.loadShader(GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, this.vShaderStr);
        this.fragmentShader = this.loadShader(GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, this.fShaderStr);

        // Setup Program
        int program = GL20.glCreateProgram();

        if(program == 0) {
            return;
        }

        GL20.glAttachShader(program, this.vertexShader);
        GL20.glAttachShader(program, this.fragmentShader);

        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vPosition");

        GL20.glLinkProgram(program);

        if(GL20.glGetProgrami(program, GL20.GL_LINK_STATUS) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error Creating Program: " + GL20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            GL20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            return;
        }

        this.programObject = program;
    }

    public void draw() {
        this.create();
        GL20.glUseProgram(this.programObject);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao_handle);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
        this.dispose();
    }

    public void draw(boolean useVAO) {
        if(useVAO) {
            this.draw();
        } else {
            this.create();
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vbo_handle);
            GL11.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0L);
            GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this.ibo_handle);
            GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, this.indicies.length, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0L);
            GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
            this.dispose();
        }
    }

    public void dispose() {
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vao_handle);
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(vbo_handle);
        GL30.glDeleteVertexArrays(ibo_handle);

        this.vao_handle = -1;
        this.vbo_handle = -1;
        this.ibo_handle = -1;
    }

    private int loadShader(int type, String shaderSrc) {
        int shader;

        shader = GL20.glCreateShader(type);

        if(shader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }

        GL20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderSrc);
        GL20.glCompileShader(shader);

        if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shader, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error Loading Shader: " + GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
            GL20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            return 0;
        }

        return shader;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Renderer.java` and `Box.java` look awfully similar.

Comment: @genpfault HAHAHAHAHA! In fact, box might just be impersonating renderer... ill cuff em. (Fixed)

Comment: @genpfault Do I have to bind the vertices and indices? I didn't have to do anything like that on the android platform.

Comment: Yes you need to bind the vbo buffers, or you could switch remove those deprecated `glVertexPointer`, etc. and look up how to crate a VAO, which uses VBOs.

Comment: @Vallentin - Got it working, sort of. I used this tutorial: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/ - How do I go about using a short buffer to index the verts so that I can make a square? Or am I suppose to use the indicies short buffer with glVertexAttribPointer()?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but for the IBO (indices) you just create it like you wound normally, and then after you've called the `glVertexAttribPointer()` and connecting the VBO data, then you just call `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices_handle);` to connect the IBO to the VAO.

Comment: @Vallentin How do I generate a IBO ID? Did not see any functions to generate any, but glBindBuffer() asks for an id (int), not the buffer itself.

Comment: In the same way you generate a handle/an id for a VBO (Vertex Buffer Object) call `glGenBuffers()`, IBO stands for Index Buffer Object, as you can see both of the names contains the word Buffer, thereby use `glGenBuffers()`. It's a god rule to remember.

Comment: @Vallentin Ok, so I put my updated code at the bottom of the question. I only getting half of a square still. (Triangle). It is a good looking one, but still not what I want. haha. Any tips?

Comment: I will write an answer instead, much easier.

Comment: I've posted my answer, if anything doesn't work tell me and I will help you.

Comment: @Vallentin Will do, thank you so much for taking the time to explain. Will be going over you answer in a couple minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just showing you what you asked for in the comments, I will demonstrate how you create, render and dispose a VAO using a VBO and IBO.

- `VAO` <=> Vertex Array Object
- `VBO` <=> Vertex Buffer Object
- `IBO` <=> Index Buffer Object

## Creating VAO, VBO & IBO

The `vao_handle`, `vbo_handle` and `ibo_handle` is 3 integers containing the id/handle, these 3 variables are used in the whole following code.

- `vbo_data` <=> `FloatBuffer` containing the vertices
- `ibo_data` <=> `IntBuffer` containing the indices

The two above variables are used in the following code.

```
// Creating the VBO
vbo_handle = glGenBuffers();

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_handle);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Creating the IBO
ibo_handle = glGenBuffers();

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo_handle );
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo_data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

// Creating the VAO
vao_handle = glGenVertexArrays();

glBindVertexArray(vao_handle);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_handle);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(INDEX); // Place your own INDEX value in the parenthesis
glVertexAttribPointer(INDEX, SIZE, TYPE, NORMALIZED, STRIDE, OFFSET); // Replace all the VARIABLES with the values which fit to your VAO, VBO and IBO

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo_handle);

glBindVertexArray(0);

/*
 * Remember that the INDEX given in the
 * glEnableVertexAttribArray() and in
 * glVertexAttribPointer() is the same
 * INDEX used in Shaders (GLSL)
 *
 * If the INDEX is 0 then in GLSL it
 * should look like this
 * GLSL: layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
 *
 * ^ we can ignore this if you aren't
 * using Shaders, though keep it in mind
 * since we might need it in the future
 */
```

## Rendering VAO

```
glBindVertexArray(vao_handle);
glDrawElements(MODE, SIZE, TYPE, OFFSET); // Again replace the variables, so it fits to your VAO, VBO and IBO
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

## Dispose VAO, VBO & IBO

This is how you delete the different buffers, which is a good thing to do, when you close the program or if at some point you don't need them anymore.

```
glDeleteVertexArrays(vao_handle); // Deletes the VAO
glDeleteBuffers(vbo_handle); // Deletes the VBO
glDeleteBuffers(ibo_handle); // Deletes the IBO

vao_handle = -1;
vbo_handle = -1;
ibo_handle = -1;
```

Comment: What type should I use for glVertexAttribPointer()?

Comment: If the vertex data is floats (Which it is in my example, since I used a FloatBuffer) then the type should be `GL_FLOAT`

Comment: Now I just get a green screen from the GL11.glClearColor();. There is no box being rendered. Updated the "Updated Code" with the new code. What did I miss?

Comment: When working with OpenGL buffers you need to call `.flip();` and not `.position(0);` on the FloatBuffers, IntBuffers, etc. Try that and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Now when I'm thinking about it, I actually think VAOs kinda require a Shader.

Comment: I didn't know that it needed a shader if it was not colored and left blank texture wise. Is it just need a vertex shader? Or does it also need a frag shader for even white color?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it requires a Shader, and it needs both a Vertex and Fragment Shader.

Comment: Ok, I updated my "Updated Code" for Box.java. I added a vertex and frag shader. It is not working though, not exactly sure what to do next. srry - Can you look it over?

Comment: Found out the issue with the frag shader. Had ver instead of vec. Haha. Everything runs fine, but still no box.

Comment: Went to this site: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/ - I think that even without shaders, it should still draw. They even had a VAO and it still drew a white box without shaders. Still looking over, will stay posted.

Comment: Got it working - part of it, ill put code above. However, I used a separate draw method that did not use the VAO. So VAO still does not work, but VBO with IBO method does atm. Thanks! :) -- Also, I use the boolean false for the draw(boolean). Kinda weird, but just trying to get code to work.

Comment: Great, though remember `glVertexPointer`, etc calls are deprecated in the newer versions of OpenGL! :)